# How to instant update recyclerview with sqlite database table?

Tags: android, sqlite

I used sqlite database to store user messages.
My code is in activity.

```
    private MyDbHandler myDbHandler;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);
myDbHandler=new MyDbHandler(MessageActivity.this,MessageReceiverId+".db",null,1);
        messagesAdapter=new MessagesAdapter(myDbHandler.sqlMessagesList(),this,messageList);

        messageList=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.message_list_user);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        messageList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        messageList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        messageList.setAdapter(messagesAdapter);

sendMessageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                addMessageInSqlite();
            }
        });
private void addMessageInSqlite()
    {
        String messageText=userMessageInput.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(messageText))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "please write message first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
myDbHandler.saveNewMessageFromSender(message_push_id,messageText,"text",MessageSenderId,tsLong,MessageReceiverId);
}
```

Method of MydbHandler

```
public void saveNewMessageFromSender(String message_push_id, String messageText, String text, String messageSenderId, Long timestamp, String messageReceiverId)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_MESSAGE, messageText);
        values.put(COLUMN_FROM, messageSenderId);
        values.put(COLUMN_TYPE, text);
        values.put(COLUMN_TIMESTAMP,timestamp);
        values.put(COLUMN_PUSH_KEY,message_push_id);
        values.put(COLUMN_DELIVERY,0);
        values.put(COLUMN_SEEN,0);
        long rowInserted = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null, values);
db.close();
    }


public List<SqlMessages> sqlMessagesList()
    {
      String  query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
      List<SqlMessages> messagesList=new LinkedList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        SqlMessages sqlMessages;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                sqlMessages = new SqlMessages();

                sqlMessages.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID)));
                sqlMessages.setPushkey(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PUSH_KEY)));
                sqlMessages.setFromid(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_FROM)));
                sqlMessages.setType(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TYPE)));
                sqlMessages.setMessage(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_MESSAGE)));
                sqlMessages.setTimestamp(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TIMESTAMP)));
                sqlMessages.setDelivery(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DELIVERY)));
                sqlMessages.setSeen(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SEEN)));
                messagesList.add(sqlMessages);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return messagesList;
    }
```

This messages are shown in recyclerview perfectly only when activity create, means back from activity and come to again activity.
***I need to instant update recyclerview within activity whenever new message will store in sqlite database by the sender.***
I also used notifydatasetchanged but it not work.

Comment: You should use Local broadcast.Trigger this broadcast when message store in database.Write code of recyclerview updateinside onReciver() of broadcast.

Comment: how to use that ?

Comment: localbroadcastmanager.sendbroadcast() methodi trigger when new message saved.Make broadcasrt receiver and register inside your recycleView activiry.You can get broadcasr message when save message occurs.So if you are in recycleview activity ,you can see update in recycleview

Comment: great thing. but i dont know how to write this code

Comment: I need your recycleView activity code and your save message code for making example code.Post this full code here.

Comment: please see my corected question

Comment: I suggest that you look at [`LiveData`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata).

Comment: Yes definitely,LiveData is also solution for this question.

Comment: Livedata is also new concept for my side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LocalBroadcast for Live update of recyclerView and also Use LiveData.
I am writing code for Brodacast method.

When you save message ,call this method:

```
Intent resultsIntent=new Intent(”custom_action_broadcast");
LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager =LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(resultsIntent);
```

Inside recyclerView Activity ,make brodcast like below:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver  mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Here update your RecyclerView Here
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(“custom_action_broadcast”);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
       LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
```

Comment: "custom_action_broadcast" means what ?

Comment: "custom_action_broadcast" is action name ,but you should choose,uniq mean your package  name

Comment: Make sure : // Here update your RecyclerView Here.This part is important.

Comment: for this i need to pass adapter again ?

Comment: Yes and also no,its depend on code.But here you can pass :messagesAdapter=new MessagesAdapter(myDbHandler.sqlMessagesList(),this,messageList);
   messageList.setAdapter(messagesAdapter);
messagesAdapter.notifydatasetchanged();